# Does $ \Bbb{Q}_2$ has $\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Does $ \Bbb{Q}_2$ has $\sqrt{-1}$?

I tried to use Hensel lemma as usual.
Let $f(x)＝x^2＋1$.
But if some $a∈\Bbb{Z}$, $f(a)＝0$, then $f'(a)$ can always divide by $2$.
So I cannot use Hensel lemma.

Could you help me?

Comment: A unit in $\mathbf Z_2$ is a perfect square in $\mathbf Q_2$ iff it is $1 \bmod 8$.  Theorems 3.1 and 4.4 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf might interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach: consider $1+i$, and its minimal $\Bbb Q_2$-polynomial. You see that it’s $X^2-2X+2$, clearly $\Bbb Q_2$-irreducible by Eisenstein. So $1+i\notin\Bbb Q_2$, and thus $i\notin\Bbb Q_2$.

Answer (score 5):

No: if the monic polynomial $x^2+1$ had a root in $\Bbb Q_2$ then that root would be in the ring of integers $\Bbb Z_2$; but a root in $\Bbb Z_2$ implies that there is a root modulo $2^k$ for all $k\ge1$, contradicting the fact that $x^2+1$ has no root modulo $4$.